# why swapoff -a && swapon -a not help to Decrease the used swap in the linux machine

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, memory, swap

on the rhel version 7.5 the used swap is 12G

we change the swappiness from 10 to 1

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness

sysctl -w vm.swappiness=1

echo "vm.swappiness = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

and did the

```
swapoff -a && swapon -a
```

then from `free -g` we still see the same used swap size

so seems that the change to swappiness , and `swapoff -a && swapon -a`  , not help to decease the swap use

the only thing that I think to do is to reboot the linux machine

is it make sense ?

[image]

Comment: What is the reading of `free -g` after you `swapoff -a` only, skipping the `swapon -a`? Does it make the swap size 0?

Comment: see the update ,,,

Comment: After you run `swapoff -a` only, and if it is successful, the swap will read `0` in all columns. Looks like your OS is having issues turning off swap in the first place.

Comment: so in that case only reboot can help

Comment: Yes, reboot will most likely help

Comment: Why you need to get swap to zero? It is in most time OK to have something in swap (i.e. all leaked memory from applications like browser and so on).

Comment: we have hadoop cluster and swap isnt recommended

Comment: swapoff is SLLLLOWWWW....turn it off and wait a couples minutes before turning it on.